# zsh prompt: check whether inside git repository and not being ignored by git

Tags: zsh, git, prompt

In my `zsh` shell, I am dynamically changing prompt depending on whether I am inside `git` repository or not. I am using following git command to check:

```
if $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree >/dev/null 2>&1); then
...
```

now I also want to distinguish whether current directory is being ignored by `git`. So I have added one more check to my `if` statement:

```
if $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree >/dev/null 2>&1) && ! $(git check-ignore . >/dev/null 2>&1); then
...
```

This works fine, but I was wondering whether I could simplify this into one `git` command. Since the prompt is refreshed on every <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, it tends to slow down the shell noticeably on some slower machines.

## UPDATE

The accepted solution from @Stephen Kitt works great, except in following situation:

I am using repository across filesystems. Lets say git resides at `/.git` (because I want to track my config files in `/etc`), but I also want to track some files in `/var/foo`, which is a different partition/filesystem.

When I am located at `/` and execute following command, everything works as expected, and I get return code `1` (because `/var/foo` is being tracked):

```
# git check-ignore -q /var/foo
```

But when I am located anywhere in `/var`, the same command fails with error code `128` and following error message:

```
# git check-ignore -q /var/foo
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

But I think this is only problem with the `check-ignore` command. Otherwise git seems to work fine across filesystem. I can track files in `/var/foo` fine.

The expected behavior should be that `git check-ignore -q /var/foo` returns `1`, and `git check-ignore -q /var/bar` returns `0`, if it is not being tracked.

**how can I fix this problem?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`git check-ignore .`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) will fail with exit code 128 if `.` isn’t in a `git` repository (or any other error occurs), and with exit code 1 only if the path isn’t ignored. So you can check for the latter only:

```
git check-ignore -q . 2>/dev/null; if [ "$?" -ne "1" ]; then ...
```

Inside the `then`, you’re handling the case where `.` is ignored or not in a git repository.

To make this work across file system boundaries, set [`GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITDISCOVERYACROSSFILESYSTEMcode) to `true`:

```
GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=true git check-ignore -q . 2>/dev/null; if [ "$?" -ne "1" ]; then ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by `file system boundaries`? Does it check all the parent folders as well?

Comment: @alper see [the `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITDISCOVERYACROSSFILESYSTEMcode). That part of the answer addresses the update in the question.

Answer (score 11):

First it should be:

```
if
  git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
    ! git check-ignore . >/dev/null 2>&1
then...
```

Command substitution (`$(...)`) is to retrieve the output of a command. Here, there's no output as you're redirecting it to `/dev/null` and if there were, it would be taken as a command to execute (and check its exit status).

Note that the second command is only run if the first one succeeded.

[@StephenKitt has shown how to factorize those two commands into one `git` command](/a/627431), but if that still doesn't help wrt performance, you could always cache the information in an associative array.

```
typeset -A is_git # declared globally in your ~/.zshrc
```

```
if (( ! $+is_git[$PWD] )); then
  git check-ignore -q . 2> /dev/null
  is_git[$PWD]=$(( $? == 1 ))
fi

if (( $is_git[$PWD] )); then...
```

That cache could become stale if you rename directories, delete `.git` directories, or change your list of ignored files. You can invalidate it with `is_git=()` or by restarting `zsh` with `exec zsh`.

Another option would be to make that check only when you enter a directory using the `chpwd` hook:

```
check_git() {
  git check-ignore -q . 2> /dev/null
  (( is_git = $? == 1 ))
}
chpwd_functions+=(check_git)
```

And then, in your prompt routine, it's just a matter of:

```
if (( is_git )); then...
```

Comment: thank you. I have accepted the other answer, but your answer was also very helpful.