# zsh: check whether I am currently inside my git repository (git check-ignore)

Tags: shell, zsh, git, prompt

In my `.zshrc`, I am using following git command (from [zsh prompt: check whether inside git repository and not being ignored by git](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627429)) to check whether I am inside a git repository, so that I can change the prompt accordingly:

```
git check-ignore -q . 2>/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 1 ]] ; then
```

But this command does not distinguish whether I own this repository or not.
This could be owned by other user on the system, and I don't have write permissions.

Is it possible to check whether I own the `.git` directory or whether I have write permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you care about write permissions on the `.git` directory itself; if so,

```sh
git check-ignore -q . 2>/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 1 && -w "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git" ]]; then
```

will run the `then` block only if the current directory is a non-ignored directory in a git repository, and the relevant `.git` directory is writable for the current user.

You can use `git rev-parse` as a test for being inside a git repository too; so if you don’t care about ignored directories inside git repositories,

```
if top="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null)" && [ -w "$top/.git" ]; then
```

will determine whether the current workspace’s `.git` directory, if any, is writable.

See also `[ -O "$top/.git" ]` to check whether you *own* that directory (not standard but supported by most `test`s / shells including `zsh`)